# Why is this second query more expensive than the first?

Tags: oracle, index, performance, query-performance

While reading [Graph Databases](http://books.google.fr/books?id=wbsaAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=graph%20database&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HKLCU57aM6mu0QWhqoCoCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=graph%20database&f=false) book, I came across this excerpt:

> [image]

I can't figure out why the second query is more expensive than the first.
Indeed, both filter on the `Bob` person.

May anyone explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is assuming that PersonFriend is indexed on PersonID, but not on FriendID.  It also seems to assume that Person indexes PersonID and Person independently.

If this is the case, the first query comes back as

1. {INDEX UNIQUE SCAN Person on Person => 'Bob' get back PersonID}
2. {INDEX RANGE SCAN PersonFriend on PersonID => PersonIDs for Alice
   and Zack get back FriendID}
3. {LOOP {INDEX UNIQUE SCAN Person on PersonID} for Alice and Zack}

Then the second comes back as

1. {INDEX UNIQUE SCAN Person on Person => 'Bob' get back PersonID}
2. {TABLE ACCESS FULL PersonFriend FOR FriendID of Bob get back
   PersonID}
3. {LOOP {INDEX UNIQUE SCAN Person on PersonID} for friend(s)}

This would be an elementary relational database design error.  With a relationship table like this you would always index all keys, and the performance profile for both queries would be indistinguishable (ignoring variations in value distributions, etc).

At this point it sounds like the author is trying to show that relational databases are intrinsically deficient.

Comment: Thanks for this answer :) I was thinking the same => "The book is assuming that `PersonFriend` is indexed on `PersonID`, but not on `FriendID`". So if I well figure it out, if `FriendID` was also indexed, both queries would be similar regarding performance. Howerver the book explains that adding another index for this column (`FriendId`) would be expensive (in memory, etc..). Am I right?

Comment: One problem with database "expertise" is that it decays.  Indexes typically cost most in add/update/delete performance, but even then, it is practically unnoticeable.  The additional storage on an index I also consider unnoticeable. The cost of storage is crazy low now!  Concerns like these are fifteen years out-of-date if not more.

Comment: So you mean that the argument provided by the book isn't relevant due to the low cost of a potential index on the FriendId column?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't hesitate for a minute to add the other index.  Moreover, if the column has an FK constraint on it you're crazy not to because it increases the cost of deletes to the MASTER (Person) table.

Comment: Understood! Thanks a lot Andrew for this great answer :)